# Variable categories number in barchart (jfreechart)

Tags: java, android, charts, jfreechart

I'm using jfreechart and I'm trying to paint a different number of categories with every series. Take a look at this:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to show only non-zero values. So far by overriding the paintBar() method of the BarPainter I was able to, but space is still taken from the chart.

```
@Override
public void paintBar(Canvas canvas, BarRenderer renderer, int row, int column, RectShape bar, RectangleEdge base) {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = renderer.getPlot().getDataset();
    Number number = dataset.getValue(row, column);
    if (number == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (number.doubleValue() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    super.paintBar(canvas, renderer, row, column, bar, base);
}
```

Any idea of how could I avoid it?

Comment: Why not leave the zero values out of the dataset?

Comment: Doing that makes it not paint the bars with zero values, but as long as one of them has value > 0, space is still reserved on the series where the category has zero value.

Comment: AFAIK, that's not supported.